# Using pip packages in python scripts

Tags: python, package

I've install [this script](http://github.com/justquick/python-varnish) via [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip#downloads), but how to a reference these files as part of my script, do I need to use import or some other magic?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import` isn't magic, it's [how things get done](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: So what name do I use for the package? import python-varnish?

Comment: A quick peek inside setup.py says "varnish".